# How to config switching time of images in live tile using c#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I create a method to set live tile follow code below:

```
public static void SetLiveTile()
{

    String[] arrayImage = new String[] { "A.PNG", "B.PNG", "C.PNG" };

    int tileCount = arrayImage.Length;
    if (5 < tileCount)
        tileCount = 5;

    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);


    for (int index = 0; index < tileCount; index++)
    {
        XmlDocument tileWideXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideImage);

        XmlNodeList tileImageAttribute = tileWideXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        ((XmlElement)tileImageAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("src", arrayImage[index]);

        TileNotification tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileWideXml);
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
    }
}
```

When run code, 3 image "A.PNG" "B.PNG" "C.PNG" switch follow default time.  Could you show me how to config switching time of images?

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
 public static void SetLiveTile()
    {

        String[] arrayImage = new String[] { "A.PNG", "B.PNG", "C.PNG" };

        int tileCount = arrayImage.Length;
        if (5 < tileCount)
            tileCount = 5;

        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);

        for (int index = 0; index < tileCount; index++)
        {
            XmlDocument tileWideXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideImage);

            XmlNodeList tileImageAttribute = tileWideXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            ((XmlElement)tileImageAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("src", arrayImage[index]);

            TileNotification tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileWideXml);
            DateTimeOffset time = DateTime.Now;
            //Note: You can dynamically set the value or you can update to your value here.
            //Add 5 seconds here. 
            time.AddSeconds(5);
            Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledTileNotification stf = new ScheduledTileNotification(tileWideXml, time);

            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().AddToSchedule(stf);

            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't. Guiding the person with right code is my idea.

Comment: The line `time.AddSeconds(5);` does nothing so you may need to do a little bit of refactoring.